# Show a image stored in ntext column in crystal reports XI R2

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, visual-foxpro, crystal-reports-xi

I have to take a database from an older program and make the reports that were made in Visual Fox Pro into Crystal Reports. 
Seems that this program stored the images into a ntext data type column in some sort of codification. All I know is that Visual Fox Pro converts this ntext field into an Image. 
Can I show this image in the Crystal Reports environment?
I've tried just dropping the field into the report but it only shows the codified text instead of the image.
I've also inserted an ole object and setting the picture location formula with the database field and shows nothing.
Thanks for your replies, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this is a VFP database then there is no ntext datatype in VFP. Probably you are trying to say "general" datatype? A datatype that no VFP developer would really want to use at all (unfortunate it existed and some fellow developers used it). That field stores the OleObject's data or a link to it. I am afraid you are helpless if you can't use some foxpro code to convert those to files on disk (and there isn't a solid code that would do that always with 100% success). Here is one sample code that would save BMP files to external BMPs:

```
** Assuming there is a table 'myTable' with general field 'GenField'
** that stored BMPs in it
** Save to relative folder mybmps
Clear All
Use myTable
Scan
  SaveBMPs('myTable', 'Genfld', Recno(), "mybmps\"+Ltrim(Str(Recno())))
Endscan

Function SaveBMPs
Lparameters tcTable, tcField, tnRecNo, tcOutFileName
* tcTable - Tablename containing BMP gen field
* tcField - Gen field name
* tnRecNo - recno no extract
* tcOutFileName - path and fielname of output filename except .BMP extension (no check)
Local handle, handleout, lcTable
lcTable = "T"+Sys(2015)
Select &tcField From (m.tcTable) ;
  where Recno() = m.tnRecNo ;
  into Table (m.lcTable)
Use
handle=Fopen(m.lcTable+".fpt")
handleout=Fcreate(m.tcOutFileName)
lnSize = Fseek(m.handle, 0, 2) && Seek to eof and get size
Fseek(m.handle,599)           && Go to start of gen file
If ( m.lnSize - 599 ) % 2 = 0  && Might it be a duplicate ? Let's check
  lcFirst = Fread(m.handle, (m.lnSize - 599)/2) && Read first part to lcFirst
  lcSecond = Fread(m.handle, m.lnSize) && Read rest to lcSecond
&& lnSize is totlen
&& but fread() would stop at feof()
  Fwrite(m.handleout, m.lcFirst, m.lnSize) && Again lnSize is bigger but
&& correct size would be written
  If m.lcFirst # m.lcSecond      && It was not a duplicate, so write lcSecond too
    Fwrite(m.handleout, m.lcSecond, m.lnSize)
  Endif
Else
  Fwrite(m.handleout, ;
    fread(m.handle,m.lnSize), ;
    m.lnSize)                 && Since now we have a size at hand.
&& So let's do readwrite in one pass
Endif
Fclose(m.handle)
Fclose(m.handleout)
Erase (m.lcTable+".*")
```

Comment: Hi Cetin, thanks for your reply. It's not a VFP database, it's a SQL Server database used with a Sage program called Eurowin. So the VFP it's only used to design the reports and i'm not sure if also stores the image into the database or not. But the image is stored in a ntxext datatype 100% sure and it's codified or something like that. But if you open the report with VFP and drag and drop that ntext column into the report, it shows the image perfectly. Any idea what can I do? thank you very much

Comment: If it is really an ntext (I am still not sure) then probably it is hex encoded version of an image. Is there any possibility that you can copy & paste one sample here from SQL server (using SSMS)? It wouldn't normally show as image with a drag drop, probably your report object previewer have custom drop code to handle it.

Comment: yeah sure, here you have:

Comment: yeah sure, here you can see the logo is codified:
https://app.box.com/s/ftloq40q71g9971jm6of6zox5y051ovv

here you can see it's a ntext field. I think it was previusly a general field as you said but later they migrated to sql server and converted general fields to ntext fields:
https://app.box.com/s/0gc1t0yzem3mv9ljrbwwyu6dep6ah8u7

and here it's a .txt with all the codified image:
https://app.box.com/s/msgbdh7q498g9oqjgxjneogtfa74l0do

I'm doing the report with Crystal Reports XI R2 so, I really don't see anything that can convert that into an image.